i want to get audio file duration using nodejs
i want to get duration of audio file using nodejs for that i have two options get duration of audio file while upload from file buffer and get duration of remote audio file so which one is better and how to get duration of audio file using nodejs

Does this answer your question? How to fetch time duration of an audio file from database using nodejs?

You can use fluent-ffmpeg library for the same.
To get duration from buffer,
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

function getDurationFromBuffer(buffer) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg.ffprobe(buffer, (err, metadata) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(metadata.format.duration);
        });
    });
}

// Usage
const buffer = /* Your file buffer */;
getDurationFromBuffer(buffer)
    .then(duration => console.log('Duration:', duration))
    .catch(err => console.error('Error:', err));


To get duration from a remote url,
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffprobePath = require('@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe').path;
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobePath);

function getDurationFromURL(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg.ffprobe(url, (err, metadata) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(metadata.format.duration);
        });
    });
}

// Usage
const url = 'https://example.com/audio.mp3'; // Replace with your audio file URL
getDurationFromURL(url)
    .then(duration => console.log('Duration:', duration))
    .catch(err => console.error('Error:', err));


However, I am not very sure if the library is going to work properly because it is not properly maintained anymore. The last release was 7 years ago.

i have implement throw remote url it's working just import
const ffprobePath = require("@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe").path;
ffmpeg.setFfprobePath(ffprobePath);
